# Setting GPU fan speed using free ATI driver?

Tags: ati, xorg, visual-artifacts

Is it possible to set the GPU fan speed using the default free ati driver?

My card (X1900) was deprecated in the fglrx drivers a while back.

The free drivers seem to work with 3D, Compiz and such, but running graphics intensive programs makes my GPU heat up and produce artifacts, while the GPU fan never seems to increase. (When set to 100% in Windows it makes a massively louder noise.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok because no one else is willing to say anything. lm-sensors is the package in ubuntu that will help with your quest the first thing to find out is whether lm-sensors detects your gpu temperature sensor as this is what will probably control the speed of the GPU cooler fan. To test whether your gpu temp is detected you will need to paste this command in a terminal first.

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

This will go through a sensor detection script it will then output a section of code to add to your modules file which will load additional modules specific for your system. It should look some thing like this.

```
#----cut here----
# I2C adapter drivers
i2c-viapro
i2c-isa
# I2C chip drivers
eeprom
it87
#----cut here----
```

you will need to add this to etc/modules/ you can open it with

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

I suggest you take a look at the howto by DeMus on the Ubuntu forums as it goes in to much more detail you can check it here.
[lm-sensors howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1100205)

after you have got the output of the sensors command paste it at paste.ubuntu.com and add the link to original question and I will be able to see if you are going to be able to continue to the next level Quest!

Good luck!