# OpenSource ATI driver - Fan running at full speed all the time

Tags: graphics, radeon, fan

I know this is a common problem and have read other topics but couldn't resolve. Anyways yesterday I found a solution - I have 2 graphic cards (hybrid) and they were both on. So I turned one off and installed Jupiter for power management and from there on the fans were quiet and I was happy as hell.

However (:)), yesterday evening I also updated the system and the fan and it's noise came back. I checked whether I am using only 1 graphics card and I am.

```
c0dehunter@mintBox ~ $ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for c0dehunter: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS780M/RS780MN [Mobility Radeon HD 3200 Graphics]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fbcf0000-fbcfffff memory:fbb00000-fbbfffff
```

Maybe the problem is (false) temp reading from GPU?

```
c0dehunter@mintBox ~ $ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +47.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +115.0°C, hyst = +110.0°C)

radeon-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +127.5°C
```

The thing that is weird is that if I boot into Windows the fan is still at full power (previously it wasn't). Did I f--- up my hardware with software? :)

//OH, yes - I forgot to mention that my laptop is not hot at all. The temps are about 50°C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting gpu fan speed using free ati driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6873/setting-gpu-fan-speed-using-free-ati-driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Ati fan control](https://askubuntu.com/a/116045/26198) post worked for me in ubuntu and I also use this in Archlinux.

Comment: From the answer I can't see where to paste this "alias"?

Comment: in your ~/.bashrc

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but when booting into Windows I use the AMD control software.

Simply switch the fan control from auto to manual and then to auto again.

I have a XFX Radeon HD 6670