# Very High CPU usage on HP dv7 Laptop when IDLE

Tags: ati, laptop, cpu, overheating

I'm pretty new to Linux computing. So I finally thought of giving Ubuntu a try, by dualbooting it with Windows 8 on my hp dv7-6006tx laptop. [Laptop Specs](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c02767450&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN/)

But after installation, I immediately realised that the fan of the Laptop is spinning very hard and there's a considerable amount of heat underneath, when the laptop was on idle, IE NOTHING RUNNING. - this rarely occurs when running Windows (Unless I'm rendering or encoding movies).

So I'm not sure if this is maybe an incompatibility issue, or if I just need the latest driver software and that things? What also concerned me was how quickly it drained my battery. It didn't even last 30mins, where I can use it for over 2 hours on Windows.

Please advice me, as despite of this issue, I'm really enjoying Ubuntu and would love to make further use of it!  :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Open a Terminal and type: `ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -15`. Please add the output to you question.

Answer (score 0):

there has been several questions about this topic. it seems to be a popular problem and there are some solutions for it. check these answers:

[Gnome 3 Ati Fan always on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116005/gnome-3-ati-fan-always-on/116045#116045)
[OpenSource ATI driver - Fan running at full speed all the time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174905/opensource-ati-driver-fan-running-at-full-speed-all-the-time)