# Different Sources are reporting different CPU usage levels when system is idle, how can I determine which is accurate?

Tags: cpu-load, system-monitor, top

Sorry if this is a repost, my Google searches didn't turn up anything with an applicable solution to my issue, the closest I got was [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345444/high-cpu-usage-even-when-no-application-is-runningdesktop/)

When I posted my stats for the same question I was told not to ask the same question in a thread. So now I'm starting a new thread for the same question instead.

I have an old PC with the following specs:

- 4GB of DDR2 RAM (4x1GB @ 1333MHz)
- AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+ ×2
- Gigabyte GA-MA69VM-S2 Motherboard
- 2x 256GB SSD in a softRAID1 via ubuntu's installer
- 1TB HDD for extra space

Running:

- Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit (Server)
- Kernel Linux 3.5.0-54-generic
- GNOME 3.4.2

According to `top` my cores are running:

```
top - 14:47:56 up 8 days, 55 min,  4 users,  load average: 2.69, 3.13, 2.97
Tasks: 210 total,   4 running, 205 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 13.8%us, 10.5%sy, 72.0%ni,  3.2%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3919760k total,  3461844k used,   457916k free,   164664k buffers
Swap: 19528700k total,  1062256k used, 18466444k free,   963632k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
28746 www-data  39  19  144m  40m 3412 R   21  1.0   0:00.63 gbrowse            
 7269 root      20   0  528m  24m 9408 R   12  0.6   1292:27 gnome-system-mo    
 1311 root      20   0  233m  63m 4164 S    8  1.6 778:52.73 Xorg               
28748 www-data  39  19 38080 8216 2076 R    3  0.2   0:00.10 gbrowse            
 1208 www-data  39  19  626m 120m 3884 S    1  3.1  50:32.07 /usr/sbin/apach    
 2944 root      20   0 1370m 430m  31m S    1 11.2  54:27.70 firefox            
17696 www-data  39  19  472m 103m 4040 S    1  2.7  13:17.29 /usr/sbin/apach    
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   4:16.15 ksoftirqd/0        
  243 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0  17:38.27 md1_raid1          
 1344 mysql     20   0  481m 1996  512 S    0  0.1   8:40.40 mysqld             
22219 www-data  39  19  430m  80m 6456 S    0  2.1   3:15.41 /usr/sbin/apach    
28726 root      20   0 17456 1440 1008 R    0  0.0   0:00.03 top                
29976 www-data  39  19  493m 112m 3988 S    0  2.9  18:13.70 /usr/sbin/apach    
32406 root      20   0  761m  11m 5796 S    0  0.3   2:06.10 filezilla          
    1 root      20   0 24608 1924  896 S    0  0.0   0:01.22 init
```

According to `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` they're running:

```
cpu MHz: 2200.000
cpu MHz: 2200.000
```

According to `ps -eo pcpu,pid,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -15` (suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248900/very-high-cpu-usage-on-hp-dv7-laptop-when-idle)) they're running:|

```
%CPU   PID COMMAND
 6.7  1311 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
 4.5  2944 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
 1.7 29976 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.7 17696 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.7  1731 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.7  1208 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.7 10551 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.6 22219 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.6 22216 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.6 20784 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.6 20778 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1.6 20774 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
14.5  7269 gnome-system-monitor
 0.2  8011 pidgin
```

According to the Processes tab of the system monitor they're running:

[image]

And according to the Resources tab of the same system monitor they're running:

[image]

I never installed compiz, which is what most of the other people asking this question were pointed at as the culprit (e.g. [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2031819)), and compiz doesn't show up in my processes list, so I don't think the issue is there (unless it's hidden from me for some reason).  Any ideas as to why there is a discrepancy and how I can figure out just how much work I'm putting the old machine through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshots that these tools give you are useful when you are monitoring them, but really you need something that tracks over a little more time.  They are only taking time slices and will report spikes in applications (such as THEMSELVES) which are red herrings.

I notice you have a web server running, is the machine serving many users?  Is it possible to start the machine without running any graphical programs and then just monitor 'top' via a tty (i.e. cntrl-alt-F10)?  That might take the UI pieces out of the equation at least.

Alternatively you could try shutting down apache and seeing if the machine load is a little more stable.

I'd stick to 1 process monitoring tool (certainly at a time) so that you don't see them all reporting on each other.

Comment: This did it, I stopped apache and every one of the trackers showed ~20% CPU load and restarting apache brought the usage back up, so now I know what's causing it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that at least `top` and System Monitor are being consistent. Look at the load averages: they are consistently above 2, and given that you have a dual-core system, that means both of your CPU cores are being fully utilized over the past 1, 5 and 15 minutes respectively. This is also shown by the System Monitor CPU usage graph. As for the rest, the actual utilization of a CPU by a given set of processes is very, very volatile - they can differ from one instant to another unless there's something guiding the scheduler, like a hungry process with a high nice value.